# Generic notation for free groups

Tags: group-theory, notation

Wondering how to write the different combinations in a free group in a generic way, going off the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group):

> The **free group** $FS$ over a given set $S$ consists of all expressions (a.k.a. words, or terms) that can be built from members of $S$.

Wikipedia doesn't offer a generic notation for the set of all expressions/words/terms that can be built from $S$. Instead they just give an example:

> For example, if $S = \{a, b, c\}$, then $T = \{a, a^{−1}, b, b^{−1}, c, c^{−1}\}$, and
>   $$ab^{3}c^{-1}ca^{-1}c$$
>   is a word in $S$.

But in this (arbitrary) paper on free groups found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9711202.pdf), they seem to have some sort of generic notation (not sure):

> ...here we just give a couple of examples of test elements in the free group $F_n = gp\langle x_1,\dotsc,x_n\rangle : x_1^k,x_2^k,\dotsc x_n^k, k \geq 2 [x_1, x_2] \dot [x_3, x_4] \dot \dots \dot [x_{n-1},x_n]...$

What I'm wondering is how to define $ab^{3}c^{-1}ca^{-1}c$ generically, so something where it can handle:

1. Arbitrary number of letters (a, b, c, ...)
2. The power signs are unique to each letter in the expression.
3. $\pm$

Something along the lines of:

$$
\langle x_i^p, \dotsc , x_n^q \mid p,q \in \mathbb{N} \rangle
$$

Not sure if that is correct or there is a better more intuitive notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic  element is 
$$
x_1^{p_1} x_2^{p_2} \cdots x_n^{p_n},
$$
where $n \ge 0$,  $x_i \in S$,  $p_i \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, and $x_i \ne x_{i+1}$ for all $i \le n-1$.  This doesn't actually say much of anything though.  It just says take an arbitrary words in the generators and their inverses, and group together adjacent factors involving the same generator.

Comment: $n$ is used twice ($x_n$ and $p_n$), wondering if they should be distinguished like $x_n^{p_m}$.

Comment: @LancePollard, it's correct as is, I think.  Example:  $a^2 b^{-3} a^{-4} d^5$ where $n = 4$,  $x_4 = d$ and $p_4 = 5$.

Comment: ah that makes sense, thank you